# XML validation with XSD

Tags: php, xml, validation, xsd

I have this XML of products which I'm trying to validate.

(i keep it in xml.xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog label="global">
    <catalog label="animals" link="/animals.php">
    <subject>Subject1</subject>
     </catalog>
    <catalog label="animals" link="/animals.php">
    <subject>Subject2</subject>
     </catalog>
</catalog>
```

Generated XSD with [this tool](http://www.xmlforasp.net/codebank/system_xml_schema/buildschema/buildxmlschema.aspx): (i put in file xml.xsd)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="catalog" type="catalogType" />
  <xsd:complexType name="catalogType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="catalog" type="catalogType" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="label" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="catalogType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="subject" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="label" type="xsd:string" />
    <xsd:attribute name="link" type="xsd:string" />
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

And the PHP code which I use to test them (in php.php file):

```
<?php 

function libxml_display_error($error) 
{ 
  $return = "<br/>\n"; 
  switch ($error->level) { 
  case LIBXML_ERR_WARNING: 
  $return .= "<b>Warning $error->code</b>: "; 
  break; 
  case LIBXML_ERR_ERROR: 
  $return .= "<b>Error $error->code</b>: "; 
  break; 
  case LIBXML_ERR_FATAL: 
  $return .= "<b>Fatal Error $error->code</b>: "; 
  break; 
  } 
  $return .= trim($error->message); 
  if ($error->file) { 
  $return .= " in <b>$error->file</b>"; 
  } 
  $return .= " on line <b>$error->line</b>\n"; 

  return $return; 
} 

    function checkXMLStructure($xml_object)
    {
        $xmlElement = $xml_object->catalog;
        $dom_sxe = dom_import_simplexml($xmlElement);

        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
        $dom_sxe = $dom->importNode($dom_sxe, true);
        $dom_sxe = $dom->appendChild($dom_sxe);

        if ( !$dom->schemaValidate( dirname(__FILE__) . '/xml.xsd') ) {
            echo "BAD XML\n";
        return;
        }

        echo "*GOOD* XML!\n";
    }

// Enable user error handling 
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$xml_object = simplexml_load_file('xml.xml');
checkXMLStructure($xml_object);

// Display Errors
$errors = libxml_get_errors(); 
foreach ($errors as $error) { 
print libxml_display_error($error); 
} 
libxml_clear_errors();
```

The output:

```
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}complexType': A global complex type definition 'catalogType' does already exist. in /path/php.php on line 13
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /path/php.php:0
PHP   2. checkXMLStructure() /path/php.php:23
PHP   3. DOMDocument->schemaValidate() /path/php.php:13
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Invalid Schema in /path/php.php on line 13
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /path/php.php:0
PHP   2. checkXMLStructure() /path/php.php:23
PHP   3. DOMDocument->schemaValidate() /path/php.php:13
BAD XML
```

I need to rewrite the schema such that it will  notice the *many  elements inside the main  element (please note the same name usage).

Comment: sorry, updated in the question.

Comment: Still don't know what the question is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [QTAssistant](http://paschidev.com) to generate the schema below (which validates the XML you have provided):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by QTAssistant/W3C Schema Refactoring Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="catalog">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="catalog">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="subject" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="label" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            <xsd:attribute name="link" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="label" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

You could start from the above and tweak it as you go along.

Validation results:

[image: Validation results]

If you wish to manually fix the XSD your tool created, then make sure that you rename **only** the first two occurrences of the `catalogType` to something else (e.g. `catalogType1`).

Comment: thanks for xsd pal, but runnint with the php code above still generates errors: php php.php
BAD XML
<br/>
<b>Error 1866</b>: Element 'catalog', attribute 'link': The attribute 'link' is not allowed. on line <b>3</b>
<br/>
<b>Error 1871</b>: Element 'subject': This element is not expected. Expected is ( catalog ). on line <b>4</b>

Comment: Hi @valk, I am attaching the screen shot of the XML you posted and the XSD I generated; the validation is shown in the output panel as OK. You must be having some other problem (maybe the XML you're using?)... Are you sure the XML you just tried is the same as the one posted? I can't think of anything else :(...

Comment: well I'm very sure. and now i rechecked it. It could be that $dom->schemaValidate() has some bug, but i doubt it. Btw it's PHP 5.3, but it shouldn't make difference.

Comment: @valk, at least the schema is now loaded; however, the message doesn't make sense; you're somehow validating the nested `catalog` node instead of the root one - this is for sure. Take a look at the code, since you're not validating the root catalog, but the next one. The magic is in $xml_object->catalog; try to validate your $xml_object instead.